# Can a Google Chrome extension access the Web Bluetooth API?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, web-bluetooth

I've searched the Web Bluetooth docs and the [chrome.bluetooth docs](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/bluetooth) but it seems like they only mention Chrome Apps being able to access the API, it doesn't say anything about extensions.

Comment: **Web** API are not limited to apps. Only chrome-apps-specific API are.

Comment: Well that makes sense. I tested this I found that I couldn't run the bluetooth api in the browser action part of the extension due to an error that it wasn't compatible with this platform. However, it still works in an extensions's setting page.

Comment: Thank you for that very interesting observation, I have posted a bug on chromium to track this problem https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=994185